# How to select objects that have a certain atribute in a json file in an Angular JS project?

Tags: angularjs, api

I have a link to an API which lists movies, each movie has title,id etc...

API: http://private-5d90c-kevinhiller.apiary-mock.com/angular_challenge/horror_movies

It also has an `offers` array inside which contains a 'provider_id' property.

**I need to show how many movies are available at which provider.**

But I dont know how, the best I came up with was:

```
 {{movie.offers[0].provider_id}}
```

But that only shows the first provider on each movie.

What I want is to extract how many movies each provider has.

My Html:

```
<div ng-controller="ProviderController as provider">      
    <div  ng-repeat="movie in provider.movies">
        {{movie.offers[0].provider_id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

My Main.js:

```
app.controller('ProviderController', function($http) {
  var provider = this;
  provider.movies = [];

  $http({
    url: 'some/path/horror_movies',
    method: "GET",
  }).success(function(data) {
    provider.movies = data;
  });
});
```

Also this is the structire of the json file:

```
[{
  "id": 140524,
  "title": "Dracula Untold",
  "offers": [{
    "provider_id": 2,
    "retail_price": 14.99,
    //...
  }, {
    "provider_id": 2,
    "retail_price": 14.99,
  }, {
    "provider_id": 7,
    "retail_price": 14.99,
  }, ]
}, 
{
  "id": 138993,
  "title": "The Purge: Anarchy",
  "offers": [
    // ...
  ]
},
]
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the structure of your database to have providers at the top level. A function achieving something like this should iterate over every movies offers, something like this:

```
function getProviders (movies) {
  var providers = [],
    movie = {},
    offer = {};

  for (var i = 0, max = movies.length; i < max; i += 1) {
    movie = movies[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < movies[i].offers.length; j += 1) {
        offer = movie.offers[j];

        if (typeof providers[offer.provider_id] === 'undefined') {
            providers[offer.provider_id] = { movies: [] };
        }
        providers[offer.provider_id].movies.push(movie);
    }
  }

  return providers;  
}
```

**I started a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/d29tu8fg/1/**

Before adding a movie to a provider, you might also want to check, if that movie already exists. You only need to do that though, if – like in your data – a movie can have two different offers from the same provider.

Add the providers to the `$scope` and in your view show the length:

```
<div ng-repeat="provider in providers track by $index">
    {{provider.movies.length}}
</div>
```